# Quantify difference between two discrete 1D solutions

Tags: ode, discretization

I have an ordinary differential equation that is solved as an initial value problem using different numerical schemes. I end up with several discrete time signals that should display a reasonably identical solution but most likely have different time steps. I would like to quantify the similarity of the solutions coming from these different solvers.

Several possibilities come to mind:

- Interpolate the solutions to a common set of grid points and then take differences
- Polyfitting the solutions and compare the polynomial coefficients

Both ways seem rather inelegant to me. Is there a "standard approach" for these kind of comparisons that I am not seeing?

Comment: Search for $L^{2}$ norm. You can measure the error between your numerical solution and the analytical one as: $$\epsilon_{2} = \sqrt{\int_{\Omega} (\phi_{\mathrm{numerical}}(\mathbf{r})-\phi_{\mathrm{analytical}}(\mathbf{r}))^{2} d^{3} \mathbf{r}}$$ In your case for 1D: $$\epsilon_{2} = \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} (\phi_{\mathrm{numerical}}(x)-\phi_{\mathrm{analytical}}(x))^{2} dx}$$ You can use the discrete form: $$\epsilon_{2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i} (\phi_{\mathrm{numerical}}(x_{i})-\phi_{\mathrm{analytical}}(x_{i}))^{2}}$$

Comment: But this only works for continuous signals or when the grid points $x_i$ are identical, right? In my case, only start and end point are the same.

Comment: Using a function norm ($L^2$ or some other norm) seems to be the right way to think about this problem; but some kind of interpolation to a common base is probably necessary to calculate the norm of a difference between two functions

Comment: @Niclas No, there is no need for uniform mesh. You can calculate this $L^{2}$ norm on **any** arbitrary unstructured mesh.

Comment: It does not have to be uniform, but it requires both $\phi$ to have the same $x_i$ values, doesn't it? Remember, in my case, both of them are numerical, meaning discrete.

Comment: Interpolate using splines and compute the integral on the resulting functions

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give an answer that balances in a practical aspect to this. There are a few major pitfalls one must make sure to avoid:

1. Sampling bias; if we just work on the solution lists $\phi_i$, we are likely to get a huge bias where the time steps of the ODE solver happens to be small.
2. Changing the number of sample points (i.e. smaller timesteps) should only slightly improve the accuracy of the error, not drastically change it. Thus any sum must include a $\Delta t$ to account for this.

Simply resampling each solution on a fixed interval of $\Delta t$ would allow for a simple
$$
\epsilon_2 = \sqrt{\sum_i (\phi_{a}(t_i) - \phi_{b}(t_i))^2 \Delta t}
$$
and, in most cases, I would suspect this is more than good enough. As this step likely relatively cheap one can select a $\Delta t$ based on the smallest timestep in the simulations.

A perhaps more elegant approach taking the union of timesteps for each simulation allowing for an optimal resampling strategy, but it's hardly worth the effort as one then needs to scan for near-duplicates and consider a custom integration strategy as a simple trapezoidal rule don't be correct for the squared integrand.

Comment: Indeed, not much to worry about with interpolation. I usually interpolate all my solutions on either a uniform grid or one of the solution's grid, typically using a spline interpolation with Scipy in Python. The orders of convergence of the errors computed that way are not polluted with the interpolation error, therefore I think your right when you say that it's not worth the effort of finding a more elegant comparison method.